# Use a single ClientSession instead of creating one for every request slowed down my HTTP calls

Tags: python, aiohttp

My python program makes HTTP requests to several different sites once every few hours. At first, I didn't know the recommended way to use `aiohttp` is to create only one `ClientSession` and use it for every request in the program's lifetime. So I create a new `ClientSession` for every call. The time between request and response was 0.3 to 0.5 seconds.

After learned that I should just use one `ClientSession`, it is supposed to be faster. I modified my code. But then, the time between request and response now is 0.5 to 1.5 seconds. I see > 1 seconds response time all the time, which never happened before.

Why is the recommended way slower?

I really don't want to change it back, because it is cleaner now, and I did other adjustments (which I am sure doesn't affect the response time) in the same commit. Is there any way I can use one shared `ClientSession` and make it fast like before?

Here are the code examples:

Before:

```
async def my_func1():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(...) as resp:
            # process response

async def my_func2():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(...) as resp:
            # process response

await asyncio.gather(my_func1(), my_func2())
```

After:

```
async def my_func1(session: ClientSession):
    async with session.post(...) as resp:
        # process response
        

async def my_func2(session: ClientSession):
    async with session.get(...) as resp:
        # process response

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    await asyncio.gather(my_func1(session), my_func2(session))
```

Comment: Let me just channel my powers and remote-view your implementation. It'll take some time, though. It's surely easier to actually share some code?

Comment: @roganjosh The code is just:
Before: `with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:` in every function.
After: `def my_func(session)` now every function takes a `session` argument, and the main script run `with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:` once.
As you can see, it has not much to do with my code, probably aiohttp's internal mechanism plus the way I call it every few hours and the program's lifetime is several weeks.

Comment: Did you read the first note on https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request, how I understood that was create a Client Session per website. In your case, it sounds like your using one Client Session per several websites.

Comment: @antfuentes87 It says: "Don’t create a session per request. Most likely you need a session per application which performs all requests altogether.

More complex cases may require a session per site, e.g. one for Github and other one for Facebook APIs. Anyway making a session for every request is a very bad idea."

Doesn't sound like I have to use different sessions for different sites. I thought it is just a way to shorten the request URL. Does it affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

After using different `ClientSession` for different site as @antfuentes87 suggested, problem seems solved.

Running two days, response time stay at 0.2 to 0.5 seconds.

Code sample:

```
async def my_func1(session: ClientSession):
    async with session.post(...) as resp:
        # process response
        

async def my_func2(session: ClientSession):
    async with session.get(...) as resp:
        # process response

async with ClientSession(site1) as session1, ClientSession(site2) as session2:
    await asyncio.gather(my_func1(session1), my_func2(session2))
```